# Xcode Failed to set unique install ID on plugin

Tags: xcode

While building and running my app I simulator I came across this error

```
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to set unique install ID on plugin com.myapp.enterprise.MyExtensionEnterprise
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-03-05 06:33:17 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
```

I am running on Xcode 13.2.1 and on Monterey, Have anyone else seen this before or know how to get around it?

Comment: Same here. Did you successfully run your app in the past with the same configuration ?

Answer (score 7):

Between recreating the widget extension, deleting derived data, erasing the content on the sim, restarting xcode (so basically standard stuff multiple times), something just clicked for xcode (???) and it started working for me.

My best bet is that what happened was:

- Turned on "main app target > Build Phases > Embed App Extensions > Copy only when installing"
- Ran the app (this time it was successful, however, the widget was not present)
- Turned "main app target > Build Phases > Embed App Extensions > Copy only when installing" back off

However, this is just a wild stab, but it might work for someone else as well.
Good luck!

*forgot to say, mine is an ios widget extension

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found out that the IntentHandler.swift of an Intent Extension wasn't added to the Target Membership. Adding it to the Intent Target Membership fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, what worked was to fully remove the applications from both Apple Watch and iPhone simulators, clean the build, and it should start working.

Answer (score 1):

yes its working fine now after enable the copy only when installing
steps:
build phase => embed Foundation Extensions => enable the copy only when installing